# Adding noise to image with specific signal to noise ratio (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I want to add noise to an image with specific SNR. What is the easiest way to do that in python?
Currently I use below code to add noise but I can't control SNR:

```
matrix_noise = 255 * np.random.randint(0, 2, (image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))
matrix_noise = matrix_noise.astype('uint8')
image = cv2.add(blur, matrix_noise)
```

One way for reducing noise power is the below code:

```
matrix_noise = 255 * np.random.randint(0, 2, (image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))
for i in range(0, 4):
    temp_noise = 255 * np.random.randint(0, 2, (image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))
    matrix_noise = cv2.bitwise_and(temp_noise, matrix_noise)
matrix_noise = matrix_noise.astype('uint8')
```

But with this code I can't control the power of the noise and it is not efficient.

Comment: how do you define your SNR?

Comment: I think this is a suitable definition: residual_noise = signal - noise_reduced_signal; 
snr_after = mean( signal .^ 2 ) / mean( residual_noise .^ 2 ); 
snr_after_db = 10 * log10( snr_after )

Comment: So, if I got it correctly, you want to generate `residual_noise` so that the `snr_after` value in the above equations have some fixed value you want to fix. is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly....